# Identify Duplicate and Non-Dup records in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which contains both duplicate and distinct records in it. I have to identify which are the duplicate records and which are distinct records and split them separately in 2 different dataframes.

Input:

```
custid | cust_name | loc | prodid
1234   | John      | US  | P133
1234   | John      | US  | P133
1234   | John      | US  | P133
5678   | Mike      | CHN | P456
4325   | Peter     | RUS | P247
3458   | Andy      | IND | P764 
3458   | Andy      | IND | P764
```

Ouput:
DF 1 (Dups):

```
custid | cust_name | loc | prodid
1234   | John      | US  | P133
1234   | John      | US  | P133
1234   | John      | US  | P133
3458   | Andy      | IND | P764 
3458   | Andy      | IND | P764
```

DF2 (Non Dups):

```
custid | cust_name | loc | prodid
5678   | Mike      | CHN | P456
4325   | Peter     | RUS | P247
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a window specification to count the number of rows in each group then check the rows where `count` is greater than 1 to create a boolean flag `has_dupes` then `filter` the subsets using this flag

```
W = Window.partitionBy(*df.columns)
df = df.withColumn('has_dupes', F.count(F.lit(1)).over(W) > 1)

df_dupes = df.filter('has_dupes')
df_nodupes = df.filter('not has_dupes')
```

---

```
df_nodupes.show()
+------+---------+---+------+---------+
|custid|cust_name|loc|prodid|has_dupes|
+------+---------+---+------+---------+
|  4325|    Peter|RUS|  P247|    false|
|  5678|     Mike|CHN|  P456|    false|
+------+---------+---+------+---------+

df_dupes.show()
+------+---------+---+------+---------+
|custid|cust_name|loc|prodid|has_dupes|
+------+---------+---+------+---------+
|  1234|     John| US|  P133|     true|
|  1234|     John| US|  P133|     true|
|  1234|     John| US|  P133|     true|
|  3458|     Andy|IND|  P764|     true|
|  3458|     Andy|IND|  P764|     true|
+------+---------+---+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

using Spark SQL

```
df.createorReplaceTempView("df_main")

df_non_dup=spark.sql("""select * from df_main where custid in (select custid from df group by custid having count(*)=1)""")

df_dup=spark.sql("""select * from df_main where custid not in (select custid from df group by custid having count(*)=1)""")
```

using SPARK CORE

```
df1=df.select('*').distinct()
pandasDF1 = df1.toPandas().astype(str)
pandasDF=df.toPandas().astype(str)
pandasDF2=pandasDF[~pandasDF.isin(pandasDF1)].dropna()
df2=spark.createDataFrame(pandasDF2)
```

Comment: how can we do it in PySpark ?

Comment: this same can work in pyspark as well, do you want to do away with sql?

Comment: yes, we have to do it in PySpark... also we can not consider cust_id as the PK.. there are many other fields present

Comment: check the updated answer, it will work now,
though it can be done without converting into pandas, but i have a bandwidth issue rn, will update once i am more available

Answer (score 0):

Here's one straightforward way to do it. Get a count of duplicates while doing a groupby on all the columns. Then filter on the count and create two dataframes one having duplicate customer ids and another with unique customer ids. Then join these with the original dataframe.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
### This is very important setting if you want legacy behaviour
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

data1 = [
    [1234, "John", "US", "P133"],
    [1234, "John", "US", "P133"],
    [1234, "John", "US", "P133"],
    [5678, "Mike", "CHN", "P456"],
    [4325, "Peter", "RUS", "P247"],
    [3458, "Andy", "IND", "P764"],
    [3458, "Andy", "IND", "P764"],

]



df1Columns = ["custid","cust_name","loc","prodid"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=df1Columns)



df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)


df1_count = df1.groupby(["custid","cust_name","loc","prodid"]).agg(F.count("*").alias("count"))
df1_count.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df1_select = df1_count.select("custid", "count")
df1_select.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df1_more_than_one = df1_select.filter(F.col("count") > 1)
df1_exactly_one = df1_select.filter(F.col("count") == 1)

df1_more_than_one.show(n=100, truncate=False)
df1_exactly_one.show(n=100, truncate=False)


df1_duplicates = df1.join(df1_more_than_one, on=["custid"]).drop("count")
df1_non_duplicates = df1.join(df1_exactly_one, on=["custid"]).drop("count")

print("Duplicates dataframe below")
df1_duplicates.show(n=100, truncate=False)
print("Non duplicates dataframe below")
df1_non_duplicates.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+------+---------+---+------+
|custid|cust_name|loc|prodid|
+------+---------+---+------+
|1234  |John     |US |P133  |
|1234  |John     |US |P133  |
|1234  |John     |US |P133  |
|5678  |Mike     |CHN|P456  |
|4325  |Peter    |RUS|P247  |
|3458  |Andy     |IND|P764  |
|3458  |Andy     |IND|P764  |
+------+---------+---+------+

+------+---------+---+------+-----+
|custid|cust_name|loc|prodid|count|
+------+---------+---+------+-----+
|5678  |Mike     |CHN|P456  |1    |
|1234  |John     |US |P133  |3    |
|3458  |Andy     |IND|P764  |2    |
|4325  |Peter    |RUS|P247  |1    |
+------+---------+---+------+-----+

+------+-----+
|custid|count|
+------+-----+
|5678  |1    |
|1234  |3    |
|3458  |2    |
|4325  |1    |
+------+-----+

+------+-----+
|custid|count|
+------+-----+
|1234  |3    |
|3458  |2    |
+------+-----+

+------+-----+
|custid|count|
+------+-----+
|5678  |1    |
|4325  |1    |
+------+-----+

Duplicates dataframe below
+------+---------+---+------+
|custid|cust_name|loc|prodid|
+------+---------+---+------+
|1234  |John     |US |P133  |
|1234  |John     |US |P133  |
|1234  |John     |US |P133  |
|3458  |Andy     |IND|P764  |
|3458  |Andy     |IND|P764  |
+------+---------+---+------+

Non duplicates dataframe below
+------+---------+---+------+
|custid|cust_name|loc|prodid|
+------+---------+---+------+
|5678  |Mike     |CHN|P456  |
|4325  |Peter    |RUS|P247  |
+------+---------+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df_basket1.join(
    df_basket1.groupBy(df_basket1.columns).agg((f.count("*")>1).cast("int").alias("Duplicate_indicator")),
    on=df_basket1.columns,
    how="inner"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**